# How add safesearch in request?

Tags: python, image, python-requests

I'm download all wikipedia titles, but some articles don't have opengraph images. So i have a ideia to search the name of article in google images and associate with the article by opengraph, but there's images that is inappropriate. I know there is safesearch in google images, But how i can do this in code via requests in python?

```
urlgoogle = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='+title+'&source=lnms&tbm=isch&tbs=isz:lt,islt:2mp'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5)' +
           'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,' +
           'like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(urlgoogle,headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [to this article](https://blog.securly.com/2015/04/01/how-to-enable-google-safe-search/), its all about adding `?&safe=active` to your url. So your Url would look like:

```
urlgoogle = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='+title+'&source=lnms&tbm=isch&tbs=isz:lt,islt:2mp&safe=active'
```